# callingTab layout from ListView(contains 2 arrays with text and images )and Tab Layout should contain 3 activities one for displaying image

Tags: android

When I call tab layout from methods using intents, it's showing "application has stopped".

```
 @Overrideenter code here
----------

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(position==0)
                {
                Intent ii = new Intent(CustomizedVeg.this,TabMainLayoutActivity1.class);
                //ii.putExtra("pos", position);
                startActivity(ii); 

                }

            }

        });

Tab layout activity.java

public class TabMainLayoutActivity1 extends TabActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabmainactivity);
        Resources resource = getResources();
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        // Tab1
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecTab1;
        Intent tab1Intent;
        tabSpecTab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
        tab1Intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1Activty.class);

        tabSpecTab1.setIndicator("Image");
        tabSpecTab1.setContent(tab1Intent);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecTab1);
        // tab2
        TabSpec tabSpecTab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");
        Intent tab2Intent = new Intent().setClass(TabMainLayoutActivity1.this,
                Tab2Activity.class);

        tabSpecTab2.setIndicator("Ingredients");
        tabSpecTab2.setContent(tab2Intent);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecTab2);
        // tab3
        TabSpec tabSpecTab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3");
        Intent tab3Intent = new Intent().setClass(TabMainLayoutActivity1.this,
                Tab3Activity.class);

        tabSpecTab3.setIndicator("recipe");
        tabSpecTab3.setContent(tab3Intent);
        // adding all tab

        //http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-tab-layout-in-android/28153

        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecTab3);
        // //set Windows tab as default (zero based)
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

        final int height = 45;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = height;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = height;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = height;

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("Tab id", "" + tabId);
                setTitle(tabI`enter code here`d);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

From this I need to call Tab layout through intent which consists of 3 tab activities; first should display images. Second should display text in `tableLayout`. Third should contain text description. `listView` contains:

```
 String[] a ={"one","two","three","four","five"};
 int[] images={five images };
```

I want to display from tab layout when call intent from listview. Tab layout should contain 3 activities;

1. **ActvityA.java**
   //it should contain linear layout and imageview for displaying images from listview
2. **ActivityB.java**
   it should display text
3. **ActivityC.java**
   display some text

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: Logcat messaga: 12-19 11:05:39.305: E/AndroidRuntime(13981):  at com.example.moduleoneassignmentapp1.TabMainLayoutActivity1.onCreate(TabMainLayoutActivity1.java:34)

Comment: What is line 34 of `TabMainLayoutActivity`?